# Variables to work with loops in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The Symfony framework has `loop_index`, `first` and `last` variables for working with loops.

```
{% for each link in links %}
    {% if loop_index == first %}
       .....
    {% else %}
       ....
    {%endif %}

{% end %}
```

Are there such variables or functions in rails?

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly but you can use [each_with_index](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index):

```
{% links.each_with_index do |link, index| %}
    {% if index == 0 %}
       .....
    {% else %}
       ....
    {%endif %}

{% end %}
```

Comment: Thanks Erez, it was helpful for me, but what can i do for last variable?What marked the end of a loop?

Comment: why not just use `links.first` and `links.last` then?

Comment: i can use links.first and links.last for out of loop. But when I'm in the loop can not I use them

Comment: you can do `if link == links.first` and `if link == links.last`, I guess ;) or using index `if index == links.count-1`

Comment: This is only a valid test if there's no duplicates in the array.  A better test is to stick with the indexes like @ErezRabih says and test `if index == 0` and `if index == links.size - 1`

Comment: @Zakaria you can definitely go with `index == links.size-1`
Regarding the suggesting to compare against links.first or links.last - It won't work as expected if you have repeating links in your array and one of them (the middle one for example) is the same as the last one.